# Efficient numpy array initialization to avoid side effects?

Tags: python, numpy

Basically what I need is the end result of this:

```
import numpy as np

class A:
    def __init__(self, dim):
        self.b = np.zeros(dim)

def add_to_a(a, value):
    a.b += value

dim = 10000
value1 = np.random.rand(dim)    
a = A(dim)

%%timeit add_to_a(a, value1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.64 us per loop
```

However, I would prefer changing *a* outside the function, primarily for clarity's sake, but also because I have understood that good programming style avoids having functions cause side-effects. So, I could do something like this:

```
def dont_add(dim, value):
    c = np.zeros(dim)
    c += value
    return c

%%timeit a.b += dont_add(dim, value1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.8 us per loop
```

Clearly, the decrease in performance is significant (and I will be running this as a part in a big loop). I assume this is because of numpy array initialization within the function, so I tried this:

```
d = np.empty(dim)
def dont_add2(d, value):
    d.fill(0)
    d+=value
    return d

%%timeit a.b += dont_add2(d, value1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.3 us per loop
```

Even worse.

Is there a more efficient way to have a function return a numpy array? Or should I just accept changing my instance variable within the function? (The actual function takes two instances of two completely different classes and modifies a third one; hence a function and not a method. Also, the added value is a vector evaluated within the function.)

Comment: The slowdown is not because of initialization, but writing zeros to the entire array. If all you want to do is have value stored in the array, just use `d.fill(value)` instead of having to go through two steps.

Comment: In the actual function the value will not be the same for all.

Comment: You mean value can be an array as well ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, modified the question now.

Comment: It's important to point out that `dont_add2` still has side-effects...

Comment: True. But those side-effects don't affect the 'clarity' as much.

Comment: So why not just make a copy of the new matrix instead of filling with zeros and then adding a new matrix ?

Comment: You mean like this?
`    d=np.zeros(dim)
    def dont_add3(d, value):
        e=d.copy()
        e+=value
        return e
    %%timeit
    a.b += dont_add3(d, value1)

    10000 loops, best of 3: 26.9 us per loop`